# Помогите пожалуйста найти значения функции sinx/x используя ряд Тейлора

Tags: c++, c++builder

Найти значения функции sinx/x используя ряд Тейлора на интервале от Хнач до Хкон з интервалом dx и точность е. Написал функцию но после второй итерации значения не правильно. Пишу в c++ builder, ниже код:

```
{
    long double xs, xe, dx, e, y;
    xs = StrToFloat(Edit1 -> Text);
    xe = StrToFloat(Edit2 -> Text);
    dx = StrToFloat(Edit3 -> Text);
    e = StrToFloat(Edit4 -> Text);;
    Memo1->Lines->Append("f\tx\tn");
    for (long double x = xs; x < xe + dx/2; x += dx) {
        int n = 0;
        long double an = x;
        y = 0;
        while(fabs(an) > e){
            y+=an;
            n++;
            an*= ((pow(-1, n))*pow(x, 2*n))/fact(2*n+1);
        }
        Memo1->Lines->Append(FloatToStrF(y, ffFixed, 10, 2) + "\t" + FloatToStrF(x, ffFixed, 10, 2)
            + "\t" + IntToStr(n));
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
long double fact(int N)
{
    if(N < 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return N * fact(N - 1);
}
```

Comment: Почему вы умножаете на `x ^ (2 * n)` если функция Тейлора для `sin(x)` использует `x ^ (2n - 1)`, тогда для `sin(x) / x` будет использоваться степень `x ^ (2n - 2)` разве нет? Приведите пожалуйста, что выводит у вас и что должно выводить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще у вас ошибка в том, что если вы хотите искать значение `sin(x)/x`, то формула Тейлора будет выглядеть так:

```
sin(x)/x = 1 - x^2 / 3! + x^5 / 5! + ... + (-1)^n-1 * x^(2n - 2)/ (2n - 1)!
```

То есть вам нужно умножать не на `x ^ (2n)`, а на `x ^ (2n - 2)`.

Так же разве не лучше рассчитывать сразу факториал и степень, а не каждый раз по новой?

Вот пример кода если делать в консоли:

```
void funcTaylor(float xStart, float xFinish, float xStep, float eps) {
    long double fact = 1;
    long double pow_x = 0;
    long long int c = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    long double x = xStart;
    long double temp;
    long double sinx_x;
    long double an = 0;

    while (x + xStep <= xFinish) {
        fact = 1;
        pow_x = 1;
        sign = 1;
        c = 1;
        sinx_x = sin(x) / x;
        temp = 0;
        do {
            an = (sign * pow_x) / fact;
            temp += an;
            sign *= -1;
            fact = fact * (c + 1) * (c + 2);
            c += 2;
            pow_x *= x * x;
        } while (/*fabs(an) > eps*/sinx_x <= temp - eps || sinx_x >= temp + eps);
        cout << temp << " " << x << endl;
        x += xStep;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то смущает меня это: `while (sinx_x <= temp - eps || sinx_x >= temp + eps);` - *в определенном смысле* подгонка под ответ :) Не лучше ли воспользоваться тем, что у знакочередующегося монотонно убывающего по абсолютной величине ряда погрешность не превышает абсолютного значения последнего члена?

Comment: @Harry А я бы еще `x*x` сделал один раз до цикла, и множил бы. Да и факториал даже `long long int` он не делал - вдруг 18 степени не хватит?

Comment: @Harry не понимаю, где вы видите подгонку под ответ если честно. Стандартная проверка на соблюдение точности. Абсолютно идентичные вещи, просто мне по смыслу моё условие выхода из цикла больше нравится.

Comment: @Mikhailo а я бы факториалы в массив бы засунул, а я бы ..., а я бы ... В общем это лишние оптимизации, если автору подходит даже тот код, который он имеет, то и к моему вопросов не должно появиться (в плане оптимизации). Про `long long int` вообще не понимаю о чем вы здесь. Вроде стоит `long long int`. Другое дело я бы его заменил на `long double` тем самым при `xStart = 4.5` не будет например вывода `nan(inf)`

Comment: Я же выделил курсивом :) - я в том смысле, что есть ряды, которые вы не сможете подсчитать заранее. И нужен иной критерий, а не сравнение с точным значением. Представьте, что функции синус у вас нет. Или что надо посчитать сумму ряда, который аналитически не считается...

Comment: Ну это понятное дело, но в данном случае это `sin(x) / x` так, что лично мне приятней использовать такую проверку, как у меня :) Автор может вообще не смотреть даже на этот код. Ответ на его вопрос еще в первых предложениях дан, а это всего лишь пример мой.